# How to find number of instances of an item in a python list

Tags: python, list

I want to part of a script to be something like this.

```
if list[1] is in list.pop n times:
      return True
```

Comment: Do you want to get the count of element `1` in your list?

Comment: Also, do not name your variable `list` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use:

```
list.count(element)
```

Example:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,2,1].count(1)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Number of items in a list:

```
len(myList)
```

Number of times the `i`th element occurs in a list:

```
myList.count(mylist[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1, 2, 3, 1, 1])
Counter({1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1})
>>>
```

This is good if you want to get all the counts of the distinct elements in the list one time.

Comment: This can potentially be a good solution, but you might want to expand on how the OP can use it to do what he wants.